# Warning developers in Visual Studio if C# expression is used (or throw error)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

Does anybody know of a way to prevent developers from using a particular type of expression in a Visual Studio C# code base? I have seen that analysers might be the way to go here.

I would like Visual Studio to warn developers when they use `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.UtcNow` in our code base.

As far as my analysis goes, I don't think we will ever need to use `DateTime.Now` in our API code base, so I'm also pondering the idea of throwing errors at compilation if `DateTime.Now` is used, in case unit testing doesn't cover this case.

The reason I want to do this is to prevent any non UTC time values from making their way into the database. Senior developers are solid on this, however I have seen time and time again `DateTime.Now` being used by less senior developers, and I would like to automate the management of this.

I know that setting server time zones to UTC could negate this, however I'd like to solve the issue closer to the cause.

Are there any existing tools out there I could leverage, that anyone knows of, or should I write my own analyser?

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: A pre-build action that searches code base for the string "DateTime.Now" and fails if it finds one?

Comment: You may wish to have a squiz at `StyleCop Analyzers`. _There isn't something pre-existing for this, but it may gve you some tips for writing one yourself._

Comment: I'd also say never use DateTime, but DateTimeOffset.... Also I'd put getting "Now" behind an interface so you can easily inject a time provider

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Rosalyn example:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp; //NuGet package
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System;

namespace StackOverflow_RosalynExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
using System;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            DateTime example = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}");

            var rewriter = new DateTimeUtcEnsurer();
            var result = rewriter.Visit(tree.GetRoot());
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToFullString());
            Console.ReadKey(); //DateTime.Now -> DateTime.UtcNow
        }
    }

    public class DateTimeUtcEnsurer : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
    {
        public override SyntaxNode VisitMemberAccessExpression(MemberAccessExpressionSyntax node)
        {
            var dateTimeNow = SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression("DateTime.Now") as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
            if (SyntaxFactory.AreEquivalent(node, dateTimeNow))
            {
                var dateTimeUtcNow = SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression("DateTime.UtcNow") as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
                dateTimeUtcNow = dateTimeUtcNow.WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.ParseTrailingTrivia(" /*Silly junior dev ;)*/"));
                return dateTimeUtcNow;
            }
            return base.VisitMemberAccessExpression(node);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just to give you an idea of how to use [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), a C# compiler tool. Here, I use it to convert a string to a C# [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), modify the AST directly, and then toString the AST.

The big advantage of manipulating the AST over, say directly manipulating text via [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), is safety. (Admittedly less important in this example).

For your needs, you could adjust this example to accept a file directory as a command line argument and run the rewriter against all files ending in cs. (I did something similar last year; ~10,000 files in ~20 seconds). Then, you could run the enforcement tool before each check-in to source control.

Alternatively, you could make an active code-analyzer, a la intellisense. (Roslyn is probably more geared for that anyways.)

Good luck!